# what is the architecture set for all device working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

what is the setting for architecture and valid architecture to be used for creating a own framework, so it can be export in with App code ?

```
armv6
armv7
armv7s
arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need armv6. All devices newer than the iPhone 3GS have armv7 or newer. The iPad 2 is the oldest armv7 device that still runs iOS 9.

Comment: need to export the universal framework that will client use to export in both simmulater and device ?

Comment: If you also need simulator, then you need x64 too.

Comment: i need to export universal framework ! please need lipo tool etc